# Setting up OpenCV in Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm a bit new to ubuntu. What I'm trying to do is to setup a OpenCv project with python in Ubuntu. My selected IDE is Visual Studio Code. I installed Python for ubuntu and then I installed the plugin in the VS code itself and I used the following command to install Open CV in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

When I import cv2 to my code in VSCode it want work. Any suggestion or help to configure OpenCv in VSCode. This will be a greate help and thank you in advance

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Opencv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2

This is th error message @M.T

Comment: Could you also provide output of `python --version` and `python -m cv2` from terminal?

Comment: Python version is Python 2.7.13
and for python -m cv2
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named cv2

this is the error

Comment: Check if opencv is in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. If yes, check output of `echo $PYTHONPATH` in terminal. If this does not contain `site-packages`, try after adding it, ` export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Otherwise, I suggest going brute force and doing something like [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Open CV was not in site-packages but when I installed Pycharm it started to work